# Sending a header in an api call being used as source

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the jquery code snippet pasted below to search for users .

```
$( function() {
            $( "#users-search" ).autocomplete({
              source: appGetSecureURL("/api/web/Searchuser),
              select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#users-search").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#js-autocomplete-input").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#users-search-uuid").val(ui.item.value);
                },
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#users-search").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#js-autocomplete-input").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#users-search-uuid").val(ui.item.value);
                },
                create: function (e) {
                    $(this).prev('.ui-helper-hidden-accessible').remove();
                }
            }).autocomplete("widget").addClass("typeahead dropdown-menu");
        });
```

I am also implementing jwttoken authorization for the api calls. For this I add headers to the ajax api call before sending it. the code used to add headers is:-

```
headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ getTokenValue() }
```

Can anyone guide me on how I can add header to the api call when it is being used as src.If I use something like '/api/web/Searchuser?token =' + getTokenValue() , the token is not being refreshed when it expires.

Comment: As far as I remember you have to use a function as source and in this function you can then do a AJAX POST request

Comment: It works without a function also , the way in which I have implemented , but I can consider your suggestion also if I do not find any other solution

Comment: So your API is able to receive the token in the URL? I can't imagine. And even if why should the token not be refreshed when you send it as GET?

Comment: Not the token but the user resultset . for fetching the token I am using javascript function getTokenValue